# Converting decimal to binary error (C)

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I've recently started programming in C and I really can't find the error here no matter how hard I try.

```
char* dec2Bin(int number) {
    char* bin = calloc(9, sizeof(char));
    if(bin!=NULL) {
      bin[8] = '\0';
      int i = 7;
      while(number != 0 && i>=0){
          bin[i] = (number%2) +'0';
          number/=2;
          i--;
      }
    }
    return bin;
}


int main() {
    int number;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    char* bin = dec2Bin(number);
    if(bin!=NULL) {
      printf("%s", bin);
      free(bin);
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

It displays nothing after I enter the number and oddly when I do a printf in the function loop it does print something for bin[i].

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Perhaps a good time to learn how to use the debugger

Comment: @RadLexus: Heh, no. I was completely wrong. It's actually *quite excessively* null-terminated. That's actually the bug.

Comment: @EdHeal I'm new to C programming, I did try to run my program using gdb but it exits correctly and I don't really know how to use other functions, I checked if there was any problem with writing/reading values in my array with valgrind but it returned nothing unusual, if you have a good tutorial, I'd gladly take it

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you, that solved my problem! However could you explain to me what was wrong with checking number!=0 ?

Comment: @RadLexus I didn't get your answer, could you please tell me what you mean by _excessively null-terminated_ ? Thanks again

Comment: @aslad as shown by the answer from Parnab Sanyal.

Comment: @aslad - Please learn to use a debugger. It has lots of features and I suggest you try them out. It will make your job a lot more preductive

Comment: @EdHeal I know it would, I only had one week to learn C and I have an exam on Monday (I'm still studying) so I didn't have much time to get used to the tools and not using an IDE with a graphical debugger included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)` allocates `nmemb` number of memory blocks and initializes them with `0` which gets typecasted to `\0` character for this scenario. Now, `printf` will print the `bin` string until it gets a `\0` character. Lets take a example. If I input `12` output should be `1100`. But in your `bin` string it is `\0\0\0\01100\0`. And thus `printf` stops printing after it encounters the first `\0` character.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
char* int2Bin(int number) 
{
    int bits = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;
    char* bin = calloc(bits + 1, sizeof(char));
    bin[bits] = '\0';
    for (int i = bits - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        bin[i] = (number % 2) + '0';
        number /= 2;
    }
    return bin;
}
```

Explanation: `CHAR_BIT` (in `<limits.h>`) is the number of bits in a `char`, and `sizeof(int)` is the number of `char`s in an `int`.

Your code probably doesn't display anything because your loop stops before the first char of the allocated array is reached, so this is probably still `'\0'` and is therefore considered an empty string.

Instead of using the slower `%` and `/`, you can do:

```
        bin[i] = (number & 1) + '0';
        number >>= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    after  char* bin = calloc(9, sizeof(char));
```

put following code

```
      for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
       bin[i]='0';
```

because you are filling your bin from right to left. but if you will not fill upto 0 location of bin it means bin staring position contains '\0' initialize by calloc function

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)`

Comment: Yes , you are right by mistake I wrote 9 thanks @WeatherVane for correcting me.